# Can a module compilation happen before it's dependency tests are over?

Tags: maven

Let's say I have a multi module project in maven with two projects A and B. A depends on B.

If I run a parallel build (mvn -T 2C ...) then module B will be compiled, tested and then module A will be compiled and tested. Something like :

B compile
B tests
A compile
A tests

To speedup things, I would like to start A's compilation (and maybe even tests) before (well actually during...) B's tests.

In other words, Is there an option in maven allowing to have phase granularity instead of module ganularity while doing parallel builds ?

Comment: Can you tell how long your build take and how many modules / tests you have cause you are asking to improve build speed on your side? Have you checked what the real cause of the performance issue is? Which Maven version you are using?

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer to this: No there exist no such option.

A longer answer:

It wouldn't make sense, cause running the tests after the code has compiled is one of the foundations here to have reliable code.

If you think further about that: Lets say it would be possible to do such thing.

You run the compile of module B and in parallel you let module A run it's compilation as well. So the questions comes at the point where in Module B the tests will fail ? What does that mean? The start of the compilation for module A was useless cause you have counted on wrong code (failing tests).

Comment: I understand your point, and of course I thought about that. My reasoning was the following : If the B tests fail, yes, the compilation of module A is useless and therefore build should stop. But if B tests pass then I've been able to save some compilation time (and eventually some testing time, if I'm beeing greedy...) To put it differently, a dependency A -> B in the graph could be more "flexible" as long as there is no side effect (like deploying A for instance, which you really don't want to do if B tests are failing)

Comment: You could of course think about such things in theory. But it's very hard to handle such things in practical. The [takari smart builder](https://github.com/takari/takari-smart-builder) might be interesting for you. Apart from that I have my doubts to save so much time in comparison to the  effort to get this running...